# Link to dynamically created div on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a navigation bar drop down menu that lists event titles stored in the database. I am trying to allow a user to click one of these links and bring the page to the specified event that was clicked. The problem is the target event is dynamically created by the database.

I believe I am having a concurrency issue because the ajax request is not completed that grabs the event and dynamically creates it. Is there a way to link to the page and wait for the event to be created from the database and scroll down to the object div.

Here is one of the links from the nav bar:

```
<a href="events.php#2">The Choice </a>
```

Here is the target div on the events.php page:

```
<div id='2'>Dynamic content</div>
```

Is there something I can do in Javascript or PHP I can do to wait for this to load? Maybe fire a function by accessing a hidden div then the function will scroll to the div?

Comment: Please post a small section of the code that is complete and shows the issue you are facing.

Comment: And never start a name class/id with a number.

Comment: Not sure what else you want me to post I tried to simplify this as much as possible. I just need to link to another page wait for the ajax request to finish then scroll to the target div. This does not work because the id I linked to is not loaded yet. When I am on the same page it works fine. This is strictly a concurrency issue I am just wondering if there is a way to wait for the ajax request to complete before linking to the specific div.

Comment: If you want to see how the content is created I can show you or the ajax request?

Comment: Ok I will refactor the id name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the page won't scroll on load because the div does not exist, scroll to it once it does exists. This presumably happen on the success of the ajax query, so when that occurs, scroll your page down to the new div.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html"
  //whatever this ajax is supposed to do.
}).success(function() {
  //make the new div
  $('body').append('<div id="newDiv></div>')
  //scroll to the new div
  $('html, body').animate({
    // window.location.hash is the div you want to scroll to as set by the link on the other page, and it even comes pre hashed ("#whatever").
    scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: If there are several events on the page created how can I specify which one to scroll to. Can I pass a value through a link from the previous page? Can I do this in php somehow where it would fill a session variable possibly to know which div I am requesting and be null if the page is just being loaded normally?

Comment: `window.location.hash` will give you the query param. I'll edit the answer with this.